# How can I transfer the formatting of an object to another in a Google Drawings?

Tags: google-drive, google-drawings

In a Google Docs Drawings, how can I **transfer** the orange background and red outline of the box on the left **to the other boxes**, e.g. with something like a "format transfer" icon (the broom) in Excel and Google Spreadsheets:

[image: Boxes]

Comment: I searched for such a feature recently, too. I found none, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not available and unless Google will decide to implement, there is nothing we can do about it at the moment.